# Using jav8 lib (Java Scripting with v8 engine) on Android

Tags: javascript, android, v8

I need to execute JavaScript code from Java so i tried to use [jav8](http://code.google.com/p/jav8/) lib. Is an implementation of the Java Scripting API base on the Google V8 Javascript engine.

I link jav8.jar and jsr223.jar to the project as referenced libraries, i can import all the classes that i need.
But when i run the app it breaks at the first line:

```
ScriptEngineManager manager = new ScriptEngineManager();
ScriptEngine engine = manager.getEngineByName("jav8");
```

The debugger said this:

```
NoClassDefFoundError
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Are you sure that the correct way to reference the `jav8` engine?

Comment: I think so, check [this](http://code.google.com/p/jav8/wiki/HowToBuild) out.
<pre> 
Prebuild Packages
If you want to try Jav8 ASAP, we suggest you use the prebuild packages for your platform.

Please downloads the package for the Windows, Linux/Debian or Android system. 
<code>

The Android make file is at the [source code page](http://code.google.com/p/jav8/source/browse/#svn%2Ftrunk) of the project. So i think it can be built with NDK

Comment: No, what I mean is, are you supposed to be doing manager.getEngineByName("jav8") instead of some other literal like manager.getEngineByName("jav8Eng")? Or something like that anyway

Comment: I am testing the lib in Java (not Android) and it works perfectly, is an issue with android. The author said that it works on android, so i am doing something wrong when i link it.

Comment: @MaxiRuani Did you manage to get it to work? I'm considering using Jav8 for an Android project and I was wondering why the prebuild package was removed from Github.

Comment: Check this [link](https://code.google.com/p/jav8/). However I couldn't manage to get it work. If you can, let me now! Thanks

Comment: did you list all the engines available to Java8, i think its "Nashorn". List<ScriptEngineFactory> allFactories = new ScriptEngineManager().getEngineFactories();

  for(ScriptEngineFactory engineFactory : allFactories){
      System.out.println("Engine Name" + engineFactory.getEngineName());
 }